# Vue Router: evitar que usuário acesse a rota de login se ele já estiver logado

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou configurando as rotas da minha aplicação em [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org), inicialmente esta tudo OK, após fazer o login o usuário é redirecionado para o `dashboard`, agora minha dúvida é como posso evitar que o usuário acesse a rota "`/login`" (de novo) depois que ele já fez o login e redirecioná-lo de volta à rota anterior? (que ele estava antes de digitar na barra de endereço "`/login`")

Lendo a documentação do [vue](/questions/tagged/vue), eu sei que posso utilizar das [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html), e usando a global `router.beforeEach`, que possui três parâmetros: `to`, `from` e `next`, sei que posso manipular esse comportamento usando o **from** para retornar o usuário para a rota anterior caso ele acesse o "`/login`" enquanto logado, mas ainda não consegui fazer com que ele fosse redirecionado.

eis meu exemplo de código:
**router/beforeEach.js**

```
import { checkUserToken } from 'src/utils/storageData'

const isAuthRoute = route => route.path.indexOf('/login') !== -1

const isLogged = () => !checkUserToken()

const needAuth = auth => auth === true

const beforeEach = (to, from, next) => {
  const auth = to.meta.requiresAuth

  // verifica se a rota requer autenticação
  if (needAuth(auth)) {
    // verifica se o usuário já está autenticado
    if (!isAuthRoute(to) && !isLogged()) {
      next('/login')
    } else {
      if (isLogged() && to.path === '/login') {
        from()
      }
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

export default beforeEach
```

router/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import {routes} from './routes'

import beforeEach from './beforeEach'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = Vue.router = new VueRouter({
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  saveScrollPosition: true,
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  routes
})

// pega as configurações do import acima
router.beforeEach(beforeEach)

export default router
```

Comment: Não mexi muito com o Router ainda, mas pelo que parece está tudo OK, tenta dar um log no `isLogged()` e `to.path` pra ver se está chegando nessa parte do código e se os valores estão batendo pra ver se consegue achar algo.

Comment: Tem certeza que from é uma função? Acho que você tem que usar next(from) em vez de from()

Answer (score 1):

Na rota '/login' pode ser definido o beforeCreate chamando um metodo goback(), veja https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate

```
beforeCreate () {
    if (isLogged()) {
      this.goBack()
    }
},
methods: {
    goBack () {
      window.history.length > 1
        ? this.$router.go(-1)
        : this.$router.push('/')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

bem, uma solução que usei é o seguinte, fiz uma verificação para ver se o usuário está logado e se a rota é "/login", então eu dei um next('/') para página home. e esse if fica fora do primeiro if.

```
if (isLogged() && to.path === '/login') {
    next('/')
 }
```

Comment: Tenho um post sobre um plugin que fiz com esse objetivo: http://www.vuejs-brasil.com.br/acl-vue/